# Limit of the fraction of numbers $\le n$

Tags: number-theory, limits, prime-numbers

For a set $E \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, we defined $r_n(E):=\left |{E \cap[n]}\right |$, where $[n]:=\left\{{1,2,...,n}\right\}$. I need to find a set $E^* \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ for which $\nexists \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{r_n(E^*)}{n}$. I have tried with some set formed by unions, intersections, and complements between the sets of multiples of different prime numbers, but I could not find this set.

Comment: What about the set of all numbers whose decimal representation has an odd number of digits?

Comment: Let $E$ be the set of all numbers whose decimal representation has an odd number of digits, and consider $r_9(E),r_{99}(E),r_{999}(E),r_{9999}(E),\dots.$

Answer (score 3):

In constructing such a set $E$, one useful idea is to have the set $E$ contain arbitrarily long sequences of consecutive integers, and then "miss" arbitrarily long sequences as well. If done correctly, this will guarantee that the ratio $\frac{r_n(E)}{n}$ does not have a limit.

One particular example is the set $E$ of all positive integers whose decimal expansion begins with a $1$. That is,
$$ E=\bigcup_{m=0}^{\infty}\{10^m,10^m+1,\dots,2\cdot 10^m-1\}$$
One can show in this case that
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{r_n(E)}{n}=\frac{5}{9} $$
while
$$ \liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{r_n(E)}{n}=\frac{1}{9} $$

Comment: Thanks by your help. To observe the last part, I considered $r_9(E), r_{99}(E), r_{999}(E), r_{9999}(E),....$, and $r_{19}(E),r_{199}(E),r_{1999}(E),...$

Comment: Another question: If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {r_n(A)}{n}$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {r_n(B)}{n}$ exist for $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$,, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {r_n(A \cap B)}{n}$ exists?

Comment: No, not necessarily. I think there is an old question on this site with a counterexample.